# an $L^p$ implication

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $1<p<\infty$ and $x,y\in L^p([0,1])$ such that $\|x\|_p = \|y\|_p
>  = 1$. Then the following implication holds:
>
> $$\left\|\frac{x+y}{2}\right\|_p=1\Rightarrow x=y\tag{*}$$
>
> This does not hold for $L^1([0,1])$.

I tried proving this, but I couldn't get anywhere. My idea is to look at $\|x-y\|_p$ and show that this norm is $\leq 0$ and hence $x=y$ due to the positivity of norms. I tried adding $\pm\frac{x+y}{2}$ to use the triangle equality and (*), but this did not get me anywhere.

How can I prove this implication?

Comment: Maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality will prove helpful.

Comment: Isn't that basically the triangle equality in $L^p$? What I did was estimating $\|x-y\|=\|x-\frac{x+y}{2}-y+\frac{x+y}{2}\|\leq 1 + \|\frac{x-3y}{2}\|$, but from this I can't really get anywhere. What I want to show is $\|x-y\|\leq 0$.

Comment: This was meant as a hint. You have to look closely, there is a statement about "$<$ if and only if". Check out from where this originates (which will lead you to Höler's inequality).

Comment: Hmm, may, in fact, not help. Norbert's hint, will, but it seems to be hard to find a textbook reference for that. It took me a while to find one, but it's German.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use [Clarkson's inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarkson%27s_inequalities)

Comment: Do you happen to have a (textbook) reference for that which contains a proof? I only found Hirzebruchs 'Einführung in die Funktionalanalysis', but that, to my knowledge, exists only in German

Comment: see page 77 [here](http://f3.tiera.ru/2/M_Mathematics/MC_Calculus/MCf_Functional%20analysis/Carothers%20N.L.%20A%20short%20course%20on%20Banach%20space%20theory%20(CUP,%202005)(ISBN%200521842832)(O)(198s)_MCf_.pdf)

Comment: Oh, this inequality really makes this an easy proof. I was able to find another (again german) [reference](http://www.carsten-erdmann.de/files/vertretung/Clarksonsche_Ungleichungen.pdf) for the proof, which I found very helpful.

Comment: Thank you both for the help!